# My IF condition doesn't work properly into the while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a condition so if I receive some result from the MySQL query my page shows something, and if it's not the case, it shows some other stuff. The problem is that if I do a var_dump of the mysqli fetch when there are nothing into the database, it shows it is NULL, but if I include that condition in my code, it doesn't act as I expect (doing some other stuff).

This is my code:

```
                        $consulta2="select * from noticias where idioma='EN' order by id_noticia desc ";
                        $res2 = mysqli_query ($bd,$consulta2)
                            or die ("Error en la consulta de noticias");
                            var_dump($resultado2 = mysqli_fetch_object ($res2));
                            while (($resultado2= mysqli_fetch_object ($res2))){  
                                if (($resultado2= mysqli_fetch_object ($res2)) != NULL) {
                                $titular2=$resultado2->titular;
                                $id_noticia2=$resultado2->id_noticia;
                                $contenido2=$resultado2->contenido; 
                                $tipo2=$resultado2->email;
                                $web2=$resultado2->more_info;
                                $logo=$resultado2->foto1;
                                $fecha=$resultado2->fecha;

                    
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="information_blogs">
                    <? echo "<div class='imf_icon' style='background-image: url(\"/private/fotos/$logo\")'></div>" ?>
                    <div class="imf_head">
                        <h3 style="height:unset !important">
                            <?echo $titular2?>
                        </h3>
                        <h6>
                            <?echo $fecha?>
                        </h6>
                        <div class="imf_cont">
                            <? echo getSubString($contenido2, 3000);?><br><br>
                            <a href="see_news.php?id_new=<? echo $id_noticia2;?>">Read more</a><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <? } else {
                echo "<h1>NO</h1>";
            }
         } ?>
```

Comment: Each call to `mysqli_fetch_object()` will read the next row from the database. So `var_dump` will read the first, `while` the second and then the `if` a third.

Comment: If you are finding mysqli too difficult for you then I recommend trying PDO instead. It's simpler and better for beginners

Comment: Great info, Nigel, much appreciated, I wasn't aware of that. Also, Dharman, I can''t switch to PDO as I'm working on something already created. I'm more or less new on PHP, which seems to be my issue here. Thanks both.